# get data from XMLHttprequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to get data in json format.
I have typed this code but it doesn't return anything.
where is the problem in my code?!!

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "http://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=true";


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = myfunction;

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

xmlhttp.send(null);


function myfunction() {

if (XMLHttp.readyState == 0) {
window.alert("Uninitialized");
}
if (XMLHttp.readyState == 1) {
window.alert("loading");
}
if (XMLHttp.readyState == 2) {
window.alert("loaded");
}
if (XMLHttp.readyState == 3) {
window.alert("waiting");
}
if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
window.alert("completed");
var y = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML =y[1].id;
}
}


</script>
```

in the html code, i have a div with id = "id01"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remember that javascript is case sensitive.

edit it to:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "http://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=true";


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = myfunction;

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

xmlhttp.send(null);


function myfunction() {

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
window.alert("Uninitialized");
}
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
window.alert("loading");
}
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 2) {
window.alert("loaded");
}
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 3) {
window.alert("waiting");
}
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
window.alert("completed");
var y = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML =y[1].id;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};
```

disclaimer: i took this code from http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json

Answer (score 0):

Just use `fetch`. It is the modern XMLHttpRequest.

```js
const url = "http://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=true";
fetch(url)
    .then(
        response => response.json() // .text(), etc.
        // same as function(response) {return response.json();}
    ).then(
        jsonString => {
            const json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = json[1].id;
        }
    );
```

More Info:

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

[Can I Use (75% Aug 2017)](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)

[Matt Walsh Tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)